# \ Operator not getting included in the SETFORMULA

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am executing an apps script which sets a formula in a cell as below

```
var a16_range = a4_range.getA1Notation();
formula_5 = `=INDEX(MAX(LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(${a16_range}),"(\..+)")*1))-2))`;
var a17_range = a1_range.offset(0,3);
a17_range.setFormula(formula_5);
```

after executing the cell with range a17_range is inserted as below

```
=INDEX(MAX(LEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(K43:P57),"(..+)")*1))-2))
```

without the `\`. I dont know why and not able to figure out why does it not capture the `\` while setting the formula

Please advise.

Comment: Backslashes in Javascript strings must always be escaped by doubling them: `"(\\..+)"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `\` in Javascript (within a string context) is a special symbol  for signaling that the next char should be literal.

As mentioned by the user @Heiko Theißen in the comments above, in order to literally include the backslash char in a string, you must escape this special character by doubling it (`\\`).

Please refer to the `Escape Character` section in [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) for more information.